# what is the difference between /system/app and /data/app?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android System App 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264981/android-system-app-101)

what is the difference between /system/app and /data/app? Is there some different permission in the two directory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the is different in term of permission. System app get more permission compare user app. For example: system app could do gps on/off toggle but not user app.

System app = app installed in /system/app
User app = app installed in /data/app

Answer (score 1):

/data is what is referred to by users as internal memory. This is what runs out etc. You can manually update/market update the apps in here.

/system is also internal memory but a different partition. This is where the rom is.

Comment: @tr4756 Thank you for your reply. But is there any different permission for application in the two directory. If I install the browser to /data/app, some function can not be work, but if I push it the /system/app, all the function can work well.

Comment: I wouldn't think there be any different permission other than updating/uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

`/data/app` is where your app's data is put. For example cache, shared prefs, assets, etc

`/system/app` is where your app binary is placed.
 Please anyone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you should notice the directory is /data/app not the /data/data. And /data/data is where your app's data is put.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Probably `/data/app` is not the right place for pushing your app. Thats your app does not function fully. It must be useful for some other purpose which I am not aware of right now.